# Arithmetic Mean with exponent of small numbers

Tags: rounding, mean, exponential

Due to rounding error, cannot get mean of three numbers:

```
a=-1.11e4 
b=-1.12e4
c=-1.13e4
Mean=1/3 *[exp(a)+exp(b)+exp(c)]
```

How to get the results in a log value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to find `log((exp(a) + exp(b) + exp(c)) / 3)`, but `a`, `b`, and `c` are so low that the result of `exp` underflows to 0. You can fix this by adjusting the values so `exp` doesn't underflow.

Let `d = max(a, b, c)`. Then we have the following equality:

```
M = log((exp(a) + exp(b) + exp(c)) / 3)
  = log(exp(d) * (exp(a-d) + exp(b-d) + exp(c-d)) / 3)
  = log(exp(d)) + log((exp(a-d) + exp(b-d) + exp(c-d)) / 3)
  = d + log((exp(a-d) + exp(b-d) + exp(c-d)) / 3)
```

So we can calculate the result as `d + log((exp(a-d) + exp(b-d) + exp(c-d)) / 3)`. Since `d` is equal to one of `a`, `b`, or `c`, one of the `exp` arguments is 0, and the rest are at most 0. Thus, one of the `exp` outputs is 1, and the rest are at most 1. We don't have to worry about overflow or underflow; while an underflow might still occur in one or more `exp` calls, it won't be a problem any more, since the `log` argument won't be 0.